# Path to pictures in Joomla site changed to ajax path

Tags: ajax, image, joomla, jpeg

I created a website with Joomla and YooTheme. All of a sudden, none of the pictures show anymore. What used to be path [domainname]/images/[imagename].jpg is now [domainname]/de/component/ajax/?p=image&src=[imagename].jpg. The site is http://joo.sprachgefuehl.ch/.
I don't know what caused joomla to try to load images through ajax and how to fix it to have images display again.
Does anyone have any suggestions how to resolve this?

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.